# Python Solving simultaneous equations with numpy

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, python

I wanted to solve a triplet of simultaneous equations with python. I managed to convert the equations into matrix form below:

[image: Matrix array form of simultaneous equation]

For example the first line of the equation would be

```
v0 = ps0,0 * rs0,0  + ps0,1 * rs0,1 + ps0,2 * rs0,2 
 + y(ps0,0 * v0     + ps0,1 * v1    + ps0,2 *v2)
```

I am solving for `v0,v1,v2`. I came across [linalg.solve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) from the `numpy` library however I am really lost at rearranging the matrices in the form given in their examples because I have `v0,v1,v2` in a [3x1] on the left and a [3x3] on the right.

Comment: In the equation that you wrote, the $v_0$ can come to the right to form the term $(y\cdot p_{s_{0,0}}-1)\cdot v_0$, and pass every term without $v_0,v_1,v_2$ to the other side. Doing that with all three equations gives you a system written in the form that `numpy.linalg.solve` can deal with, namely $A\begin{pmatrix}v_0\\v_1\\v_2\end{pmatrix}=b$, for some $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ not depending on $v_0,v_1,v_2$.

Comment: @Arthur This question is about mathematics, plus this site does accept questions about computer software for doing mathematics.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft I have posted my attempt of an answer. Does it look correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answering my own question following the guidance of @spiraltotheleft

I have come up with:

[image]

This matrix can be obtained from moving the v's to the same side.

Answer (score 1):

I'll see if I can't help with the following...

> > I am really lost at rearranging the matrices in the form given in their examples

---

Here's some tips for going between matrices and Python `list`s and `numpy` `array`s

$$
v =
\begin{pmatrix}
  9 \\\
  8 \\\
  7
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Where I usually see $v_{\left(1\right)} = 9$ and $v_{\left(3\right)} = 7$ is written just a bit like...

```
vList = [9, 8, 7]
vArray = np.array(vList)

# vList[0]  # -> 9
# vArray[2] # -> 7
```

... and in most programming languages the index starts at `0`, but it looks like you've got that.

---

Things get interesting with nested lists and multidimensional numpy arrays...

$$
p =
\begin{pmatrix}
  0.3 & 0.6 & 0.9 \\\
  0.4 & 0.7 & 0.8 \\\
  0.5 & 0.8 & 0.7
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which *could* be represented as a `numpy.array` as shown...

```
p = np.array([
    [0.3, 0.6, 0.9],
    [0.4, 0.7, 0.8],
    [0.5, 0.8, 0.7]
])
```

Accessing rows could then look like...

```
p[0]
# -> array([ 0.3,  0.6,  0.9])
p[2]
# -> array([0.5, 0.8, 0.7])
```

... **but** accessing cells is likely to frustrate those that want precision at a *cellular level*...

```
p[2,0]
# -> 0.5
# ... above looks okay...
p[0,0]
# -> 0.29999999999999999
# ... but that was `0.3`...
p[1,1]
# -> 0.69999999999999996
# ... and that should have been `0.7`
```

Even *funkier* than that...

```
p * 5
# -> array([[ 1.5,  3. ,  4.5],
#           [ 2. ,  3.5,  4. ],
#           [ 2.5,  4. ,  3.5]])
```

Hopefully this gave ya some traction on translating your problem into something that a computer will consider, as well as some pointers on how **not** to use `numpy`. It's fantastic but misusing it can lead to anger, and anger can lead to; well let's not even consider the paths divergent from light ;-)